# A difficult integral of reciprocal of sum of exponentials

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Consider the integral: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx}} dx$$ where $a, b, c$ are complex numbers.

I encounter such integral when dealing with Laplace transform of co-functions. It turns out that the online integral calculator couldn’t even give any result.

I suppose the integrand is well-defined since $e^x$ has no branch point on the whole complex plane.

Maybe the integrand has poles, but I believe the integral exists in the sense of Cauchy p.v..

I am a bit reluctant to use the substitution $y=e^x$ since $y^p$ in general has branch points for complex $p$.

Is there any method to compute such integral?

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: since a result in closed form is very unlikely to exist, a series as an answer will also be appreciated.

Comment: You need some restrictions on $a,b,c$, I believe. If they are all nonpositive real numbers, the integral diverges (perhaps this is encapsulated in some formula, though).

Comment: Do you expect a closed form? If it can't be found in general, would some kind of series solution be useful?

Comment: @YuriyS Any help will be appreciated. Indeed, as long as the result is in terms of $a, b, c$ then it is useful enough.

Comment: Even special cases such as $a=b=1$, $c > 0$ don't seem to have a closed form.

Comment: If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all rationally related (say $a = i d$, $b = j d$, $c = k d$ with $i,j,k$ positive integers and $d > 0$, the transformation $e^{dx} = t$ gives you the integral of a rational function, which can be done using the partial fraction decomposition of that rational function (and thus in terms of residues at the roots).  This makes a nice general solution unlikely.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If a, b, c are linearly related e.g. $a=s+id$ and $b=s+jd$ and $c=s+kd$, then are there any chances?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, there is a closed form for $a=b,c>0$ though, in terms of the hypergeometric function ${_2 F_1}$. Wolfram gives it, and I think it's not that hard to derive, from the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{2 t^{1-a}+t^{1-c}}$$

Comment: @YuriyS As you mentioned hypergeometric functions, would you like to look at my question, which nobody answered yet? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2651292/512032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this integral deserves to be studied more. Let's introduce a function of three variables:

$$f(a,b,c)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx}} dx$$

The function is obviously symmetric in all the variables.

While the integral doesn't have a closed form, what's important is: how else can we define the function and determine its properties or connect it to something else.

First, let's consider partial derivatives:

$$\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial a} =-\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{ax}}{(e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx})^2} dx$$

Same with the other two variables.

On the other hand, we have:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx}}=-\frac{ae^{ax}+be^{bx}+ce^{cx}}{(e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx})^2}$$

Thus, using integration by parts:

$$a\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial a}+b\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial b}+c\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial c}=- \int_0^\infty \frac{x(ae^{ax}+be^{bx}+ce^{cx})}{(e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx})^2} dx=$$

$$=\frac{x}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx}} \bigg|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx}}dx=-f$$

So our function obeys a first order linear PDE:

> $$a\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial a}+b\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial b}+c\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial c}+f=0$$

The form of this equation obviously generalizes to any number of exponentials in the denominator.

---

Of course, this PDE doesn't tell us much more than the integral itself. Moreover, it has infinitely more solutions than just this integral.

But maybe it might be useful in some context.

As for boundary conditions, we can look back at the integral and see that

$$\lim_{a \to +\infty} f(a,b,c)=0$$

For $a>0$ we also have:

$$\lim_{b,c \to -\infty} f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{a}$$

To this we can add (again for $a>0$):

$$f(a,0,0)=\frac{\ln 3}{2 a}$$

Same for the other variables. The above should be more than enough as far as boundary conditions go.

If we try to solve the PDE by separation of variables we have:

$$f(a,b,c)=A(\lambda,\mu) a^{\lambda} b^{ \mu-\lambda} c^{-1-\mu}$$

For some arbitrary constants $\lambda, \mu, A(\lambda,\mu)$. Since the equation is linear we can sum any number of solutions with different parameters and different amplitudes. Not sure if we can satisfy all the initial conditions that way though, I'll have to look into this further. The general solution (assuming the separation of variables of course, there are other kinds of solutions) could look like:

$$f(a,b,c)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty A(\lambda,\mu) a^{\lambda} b^{ \mu-\lambda} c^{-1-\mu} d \lambda d \mu$$

Where of course $A(\lambda,\mu)$ could be made zero for any range to keep the solution finite.

---

Now, the integral also allows us to derive a number of simple functional equations, by changing the variable. For example:

$$f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{a} f \left(1,\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a}  \right)$$

As well as a more symmetric one:

$$f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{abc} f \left(\frac{1}{ab},\frac{1}{bc},\frac{1}{ca}  \right)$$

In general:

$$f(\alpha a,\alpha b,\alpha c)=\frac{1}{\alpha} f \left(a,b,c  \right)$$

---

Additionally, if we change the variable $$e^{-x}=t$$ we obtain: $$f(a,b,c)=\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^{1-a}+t^{1-b}+t^{1-c}}$$

As Robert Israel points our in the comments, if the parameters are rational multiplies of each other, we can usually transform this to an integral of a rational function, which always has a closed form.

---

All in all, I would consider this integral to be as interesting as [Carlson elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_symmetric_form), as it too can be interpreted as the generalized several numbers mean. Might be worth looking into its properties more.

The fact that it's related to means can be trivially seen. Really, let $0<a \leq b \leq c$:

$$\frac{1}{3c}= f(c,c,c) \leq f(a,b,c) \leq f(a,a,a)= \frac{1}{3a}$$

$$a \leq \frac{1}{3 f(a,b,c)} \leq c$$

Then there exists a number $a \leq \mu \leq c$ such that:

$$f(a,b,c)=f( \mu, \mu, \mu) = \frac{1}{3 \mu}$$

As $ \mu$ represents a generalized mean of $a,b,c$, there may be some iterative algorithm which converges to it (just like arithmetic-geometric mean and Carlson three number algorithm for his integrals).

The above arguments work for any function of the form:

$$f_n(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{a_1x}+e^{a_2 x}+ \cdots + e^{a_n x}}$$

Comment: I am delighted to see the elaboration on your answer, but I think I need some more time to fully understand your ideas. Also, thanks for giving me new directions!

Comment: @Szeto, you are welcome, feel free to as any questions. In general, the family of integrals $$f_n(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{a_1x}+e^{a_2 x}+ \cdots + e^{a_n x}}$$ is an interesting kind of symmetric functions to study

Comment: Fantastic idea! My question is, why did you solve it using separation of variables? Shouldn't one use substituion techniques instead, transforming it into a different, but more easily solvable equation?

Comment: @user458276, I didn't solve it, as I doubt the separation of variables gives the original integral, i.e. they are two different kinds of solutions. And I don't see any way to simplify this equation. If you do, you could post it here though

Comment: @Szeto, see my last edit at the bottom of the post. You might be interested in the fact that this integral is related to generalized means

Comment: @YuriyS Your answer is so rich in content that you totally astonished me. If there is a fast algorithm to find $\mu$ when $a, b, c$ are given, then this integral is actually so simple. You deserve the green tick.

Comment: @Szeto, thank you, but I must warn you that this algorithm may be extremely difficult to find. Maybe impossible

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very sloppily derived series representation. I just went through the algebra without looking out for convergence and divergence problems, so I have no idea how useful this will be (in fact, it appears that the final result hardly *ever* converges).

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}+e^{cx}}
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-cx}}{e^{(a-c)x}+e^{(b-c)x}+1}dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-cx}}{1-(-e^{(a-c)x}-e^{(b-c)x})}dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-cx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(e^{(a-c)x}+e^{(b-c)x})^n dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-cx}(e^{(a-c)x}+e^{(b-c)x})^n dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-cx}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{(a-c)xk}e^{(b-c)x(n-k)} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^\infty e^{-cx}e^{(a-c)xk}e^{(b-c)x(n-k)} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^\infty e^{(a-c)xk+(b-c)x(n-k)-cx} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^\infty e^{((a-c)k+(b-c)(n-k)-c)x} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^\infty e^{(ak+bn-bk-cn-c)x} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \bigg[ \frac{e^{(ak+bn-bk-cn-c)x}}{ak+bn-bk-cn-c} \bigg]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{ak+bn-bk-cn-c}  \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(a-b)k+(b-c)n-c}  \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Maybe that simply implies that Laplace transform of co-functions rarely exists. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think one problem is that the first series expansion is valid when $|e^{(a-c) x} + e^{(b-c) x}| < 1$, but that's false when $x$ is near $0$.